# Posting a form to rails in a different view

Tags: jquery, post, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've created a feedback form that I'd like to submit in my application layout.

in `app/views/layout/application.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag "/feedback_responses", :id => "feedback-form", do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag "feedback" %>
  <%= text_area_tag "feedback" %>
<% end %>

<button id="submit-feedback">Feedback</button>
```

in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap


$( "#feedback-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Send feedback": function() {
          $.post( this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(){
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          });
        },
        "No thanks": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
    }
});


$( "#submit-feedback" ).button().click(function() {
        $( "#feedback-form" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
```

When I attempt to post, the controller logs

```
Started POST "/feedback_responses" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-09 21:54:40 -0400
  Processing by FeedbackResponsesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HOPejZ/me+tTVglsNZjLoMqs0+SLaz5+AYPWWhiTAoY=", "feedback"=>"asdf"}
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "feedback_responses" ("created_at", "feedback", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 10 Apr 2012 01:54:41 UTC +00:00], ["feedback", nil], ["updated_at", Tue, 10 Apr 2012 01:54:41 UTC +00:00]]
Redirected to http://myapp.dev/feedback_responses/7
Completed 302 Found in 51ms
```

The controller is scaffolded `app/controllers/feedback_responses_controller.rb`

```
  # POST /feedback_responses
  # POST /feedback_responses.json
  def create
    @feedback_response = FeedbackResponse.new(params[:feedback_response])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @feedback_response.save
        format.html { redirect_to @feedback_response, notice: 'Feedback response was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @feedback_response, status: :created, location: @feedback_response }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @feedback_response.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Something is misconfigured on the post or controller, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I poked around my other forms a bit deeper and figured it out.

It was the name used since that keys to the post:

```
<%= form_tag "/feedback_responses", :id => "feedback-form", do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag "feedback" %>
  <%= text_area_tag "feedback" %>
<% end %>
```

should be

```
<%= form_tag "/feedback_responses", :id => "feedback-form", do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag "feedback" %>
  <%= text_area_tag "feedback_response[feedback]" %>
<% end %>
```